# Problems with facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have a problem with a facebook app, when i try to send a message to receive with a bot i get this error.
If you need the php script to better understand the error, just ask.

```
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://4eecef78.ngrok.io/whatsapp/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

this is my index.php script

```
<?php
$access_token = "EAANXQoEiXdsBAAeeSGCv80gkk8tzo4hHYUMbfW3xCu8en9QjaLrDpT2Pj2ChO9668stns6xNao5NGyNKldw5v9yXUCnc1qvHSCuZCvhChoP59uiMZC9k27lMSRAD2ZB0qro5ABrptXHHZACHs3cDLlNggVBMLwrqWCgSjKz8lQZDZD";
$verify_token = "fb";
$hub_verify_token = null;
 //verifica del token con fb per avere accesso all'app
if(isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge'])) {
    $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
    $hub_verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];
}


if ($hub_verify_token === $verify_token) {
    echo $challenge;
}

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); //converto json in arrivo in array php

$sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id']; //prendo id sender
$message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']; //prendo testo


 $message_to_reply = 'Huh! what do you mean?';
 //messaggio di bot
//da qui in poi si può fare una funzione di send message 
//
//API Url
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$access_token;
//formatto la risposta per fb mettendo id di ricezione e messaggio di risposta
$response= [
    'recipient' => [ 'id' => $sender ],
    'message' => [ 'text' => $message_to_reply]
];

$ch = curl_init($url); //inizializzo curl per fare la post


$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($response); //traduco la response in json

//indico al curl che sarà una post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded); //appendo la risposta
//setto content type e variabili di sicurezza che non avendo tunnel ssl vanno settate cosi 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
//invio il curl finchè arriva in 'posta un messaggio'
if(!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message'])){
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

   //print var_dump($response);//stampo in console il testo di risposta da parte di fb per verifica
}



?>
```

Comment: without code we cannot help

Comment: added the code of php script

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, i was using php dev server instead of web server. Huge mistake, but at the end i got it!!